# HashMap null check in Merge Operation

Tags: java-8, collectors

Why HashMap merge is doing null check on value. HashMap supports null key and null values.So can some one please tell why null check on merge is required?

```
@Override
public V merge(K key, V value,
               BiFunction<? super V, ? super V, ? extends V> remappingFunction) {
    if (value == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    if (remappingFunction == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
```

Due to this I am unable to use `Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), this::get)` to collect values in a Map

Comment: Did you consult the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because *internally* for `Collectors.toMap`, `Map#merge` is used - you can't really do anything about it. Using the static `Collectors.toMap` is not an option (which by the way is documented to throw a `NullPointerException`).

But spinning a custom collector to be able to do what you want (which you have not shown) is not that complicated, here is an example:

```
 Map<Integer, Integer> result = Arrays.asList(null, 1, 2, 3)
            .stream()
            .collect(
                    HashMap::new,
                    (map, i) -> {
                        map.put(i, i);
                    },
                    HashMap::putAll);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `Collectors.toMap`’s documentation does not really say something about `NullPointerException`s. By the way, your lambda expression doesn’t really need the curly braces.

Answer (score 7):

The behavior is mandated by [the `Map.merge` contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

> #### Throws:
>
> …
>
> NullPointerException - if the specified key is null and this map does not support null keys ***or the value or remappingFunction is null***

Note that using `Map.merge` for [`Collectors.toMap` without a merge function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) is an implementation detail; it not only disallows `null` values, it does not provide the desired behavior for reporting duplicate keys, the Java 8 implementation wrongly reports one of the two values as key when there are duplicate keys.

In Java 9, the implementation has been completely rewritten, it does not use `Map.merge` anymore. But the new implementation is behavioral compatible, now having code explicitly throwing when the value is `null`. So the behavior of `Collectors.toMap` not accepting `null` values has been fixed in the code and is not an artifact of using `Map.merge` anymore. (Still speaking of the `toMap` collector without a merge function only.)

Unfortunately, [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) does not tell.

Comment: what do you mean that it does not use `Map#merge` anymore? I am looking at the code and actually seeing  it...

Comment: As said, *still speaking of the `toMap` collector without a merge function only*. Look for `uniqKeysMapAccumulator`. It uses `putIfAbsent`, after applying an explicit `null` check on the new value.

Comment: oh my! looked at the code, indeed what a hack with `putIfAbsent`, at least it would correctly report the key with the problem, thank you for the answer

Comment: @Eugene well, it allows correct failure reports and still bears only one hash operation per element. What more can you get…

Comment: I don't know, it's just that every time I look into the sources I'm expecting super-human code

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround for mentioned problems with null values in `toMap` and `merge`
you can try to use a custom collector in the following manner:

```
public static <T, R> Map<T, R> mergeTwoMaps(final Map<T, R> map1,
                                            final Map<T, R> map2,
                                            final BinaryOperator<R> mergeFunction) {
    return Stream.of(map1, map2).flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(HashMap::new,
                    (accumulator, entry) -> {
                        R value = accumulator.containsKey(entry.getKey()) 
                                ? mergeFunction.apply(accumulator.get(entry.getKey()), entry.getValue())
                                : entry.getValue();
                            accumulator.put(entry.getKey(), value);
                    },
                    HashMap::putAll);
}
```