# Why does Collectors.toMap require non null values

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-stream, collectors

I am putting the results of a Java 11 stream into a [`Collectors.toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)) collector. It so happens that my value-mapper (lambda) returns a null value, resulting in a `NullPointerException`, which is surprising.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:221)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$uniqKeysMapAccumulator$1(Collectors.java:178)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap$EntrySpliterator.forEachRemaining(TreeMap.java:2962)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at [my code]
```

The fatal call to `Objects.requireNonNull` is in `Collectors.uniqKeysMapAccumulator()`:

```
    private static <T, K, V>
    BiConsumer<Map<K, V>, T> uniqKeysMapAccumulator(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
                                                    Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper) {
        return (map, element) -> {
            K k = keyMapper.apply(element);
            V v = Objects.requireNonNull(valueMapper.apply(element));
            V u = map.putIfAbsent(k, v);
            if (u != null) throw duplicateKeyException(k, u, v);
        };
    }
```

The crucial expression being `Objects.requireNonNull(valueMapper.apply(element))`.

Why is the collector requiring that map **values** are non null? Is this a bug in the implementation?

---

The [`Map.merge` operation is required to reject `null` values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002680/hashmap-null-check-in-merge-operation). The documentation for the `Collectors.toMap()` methods that are given a `mergeFunction` state that it will be used by `Map.merge`. However, the `Collectors` documentation for the 2-argument `toMap()` methods (which do not have a `mergeFunction`) does not state that values must be non-null, nor does it state that `Map.merge` is invloved at all.

Comment: @Oleksandr I thought so too, but this asks *why*, not how to overcome, not sure...

Comment: @Oleksandr not really, the dupe has hints on why, but it's not like Stuart Marks came to answer that and said : this is why...

Comment: @Eugene Found some answer from Stuart Marks, in the [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8148463) report comments :)

Comment: @Oleksandr judging by that comment, it sure looks like  they simply missed that point, thank you for the bug link!

Comment: @Oleksandr well, except that this explanation does not apply to the current Java version, as it doesn’t use `Map.merge` (clearly visible in the stack trace). But never mind, I added another helpful Q&A to the list of duplicates to complete the picture.

Comment: @Eugene they missed that point in Java 8, but deliberately kept the behavior starting with Java 9. Actually, [you’ve seen this before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49004223/2711488)…

Comment: @Holger ha! thank you :)

Comment: @Holgar The question about `Map.merge` is related, but not a duplicate target. I've amended the question to clarify that and to include a link in the body. But this is still a duplicate question.